# Request error message is not available in production when using Nuxt 3

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, netlify, nuxtjs3

I'm trying to access the error message returned by the Nuxt 3 API endpoint in the client. I'm able to access the error message in local development, but once I run in production the message is not accessible, only the status code is available. Why is it not possible to access the error message?

Furthermore, I can see that the message is included in the response, but it is not available in error object.

```js
// /server/api/example-api.ts
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
    throw createError({
        statusCode: 400,
        message: "Test message",
        statusMessage: "Test message",
    });
};
```

Response:

```json
{
  "url":"/api/example-api",
  "statusCode":400,
  "statusMessage":"Test message",
  "message":"Test message",
  "stack":""
}
```

```js
// Client request
async (body: any) => {
    try {
        const response = await $fetch("/example-api", {
            method: "POST",
            body: body,
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message, err.statusMessage, err.statusCode);
    }
};
```

Print from `console.log`:

```
[POST] "/api/example-api": 400  <empty string> 400
```

If relevant, the site is deploy in Netlify.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the error message from the data object. This is how the code will look, and it should solve your problem

```
// Client request
async (body: any) => {
    try {
        const response = await $fetch("/example-api", {
            method: "POST",
            body: body,
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.data.message, err.data.statusMessage, err.data.statusCode);
    }
};
```